# randomness algorithm

Tags: c++, random, events

I need some help regarding algorithm for randomness. So Problem is.

There are 50 events going to happen in 8 hours duration. Events can happen at random times.
Now it means in each second there is a chance of event happening is 50/(8*60*60)= .001736.
How can I do this with random generation algorithm?

I can get random number

```
int r = rand();
double chance = r/RAND_MAX;
if(chance < 0.001736)
    then event happens
else
    no event
```

But most of times rand() returns 0 and 0<0.001736 and I am getting more events than required.

Any suggestions?

---

sorry I forget to mention
I calculated chance as
double chance = (static_cast )(r) / (static_cast)(RAND_MAX);

---

It removed double from static_cast

double chance = (double)r/(double)(RAND_MAX);

Comment: It would help to know what language and rand library you're using.

Comment: This question's title could stand to be alittle more descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create a list of 50 numbers.
- Fill them with a random number between 1 and 8 * 60 * 60.
- Sort them

And you have the 50 seconds.

Note that you can have duplicates.

Answer (score 7):

Both `r` and `RAND_MAX` are integers, so the expression

```
double chance = r / RAND_MAX;
```

is computed with integer arithmetic. Try:

```
double chance = 1.0 * r / RAND_MAX;
```

which will cause the division to be a floating point division.

However, a better solution would be to use a random function that returns a floating point value in the first place. If you use an integer random number generator, you will get some bias errors in your probability calculations.

Answer (score 7):

If you choose whether an event will happen in each second, you have a change of 0 events occurring or 8*60*60 events occurring.  If 50 events is a constraint, choose 50 random times during the 8 hour period and store them off.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly 50, or on average 50?

You might want to look into the [Exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) and find a library for your language that supports it.

The Exponential distribution will give you the intervals between events that occur randomly at a specified average rate.

You can "fake" it with a uniform RNG as follows:

```
    double u;
    do
    {
        // Get a uniformally-distributed random double between
        // zero (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)
        u = rng.nextDouble();
    } while (u == 0d); // Reject zero, u must be +ve for this to work.
    return (-Math.log(u)) / rate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a 28,800 element list and pull 50 elements from it to determine the time of the events?  This does assume that 2 events can't occur at the same time and each event takes 1 second of time.  You can use the random number generator to generate integer values between 0 and x so that it is possible to pick within the limits.

Comment: Why bother creating the list when you could just use the generated number as an offset from the first available time?

Comment: How would that generated number be made such that it isn't giving an unfair probability for other time values?  The idea of the list is merely to keep track of unselected values and prevent having to do a redraw where if one kept a list of taken values there may be the same selection made again.